# How do I save the text in python plots editable in svg files?

Tags: python, svg, text, latex, pgf

I am trying to save a python plot as an svg file:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('svg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Phase $\phi$')
plt.ylabel('Signal')
plt.savefig('SineSignal.svg', format = 'svg')
```

Works so far.
But once I open the file in Inkscape, I cannot edit the text anymore. Seems like python saved the text as a graphic instead as text. Because of this I am neither able to change font, fontsize etc. in Inkscape nor to search for text elements in the plots in the PDF file I create with latex.

Another option is to save the plot as PGF (mpl.use('svg') has to be replaced with mpl.use('pgf') in this case):

```
plt.savefig('SineSignal.pgf')
```

This way I am still not able to edit font/fontsize, but at least I can search for textelements in the pdf.

Any suggestions?
Using TikZ in python is not an option because the features are quite limited and the plots would look different.

Comment: SVG format is XML based fromat. Specifications can be found here, if you want to do it from scratch yourself: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/

Comment: What does this mean? I am not familiar at all with XML.

Comment: See tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp If you save code between <svg> abd </svg> tags in .svg file. More detailled in my Answer (soon).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found an answer. You can use

```
new_rc_params = {'text.usetex': False,
"svg.fonttype": 'none'
}
mpl.rcParams.update(new_rc_params)
```

to prevent the svg backend from rendering the text as paths.
For more detailed instructions take a look at [Is there an efficient way to store 2D plots as a vector graphic in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506076/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-store-2d-plots-as-a-vector-graphic-in-python).

Comment: This works very well, also for including SVG Files in Latex and having the Text typesetted.

Answer (score 1):

**Doing from scratch option**

Minimal code for SVG file with red circle; save to `circle.svg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <circle id="circle--red" cx="30" cy="30" r="30" fill="#f00"/>
</svg>
```

You need probably `<path>` to create sine wave curve within the SVG.
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp Replace `<circle>` element in above. For text, use `<text>`:
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_text.asp

If you want axises, you can generate those yourself, but using Inkscape or other SVG-able graphics editor may help to create prototype for axes.

Comment: I created the SVG file already (using python). It also looks like what I wanted to create, but apparently the text is stored as a graphic instead as text.