# Pyplot save figure without rendering LaTex expression

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, latex

I want to save the following figure as svg without rendered LaTex code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.arange(10))
plt.title(r'$\alpha$')
plt.savefig('figure.svg', format='svg')
```

Instead of `$\alpha$` I see a rendered alpha-symbol in the title. How can I change this such that the LaTeX code is not rendered?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `LaTeX `code is not rendered ? You don't need `\alpha` ?

Comment: Escape the dollar signs with \$ ?

Comment: Is it related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345077/how-do-i-save-the-text-in-python-plots-editable-in-svg-files

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to escape the dollar signs with `\$` and since my workflow is `pyplot > inkscape > latex`, I have to set the correct `matplotlibrc` parameters:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
rc_params = {'text.usetex': 'False', 'svg.fonttype': 'none'}
matplotlib.rcParams.update(rc_params)
plt.plot(np.arange(10))
plt.title(r'\$\alpha\$')
plt.savefig('figure.svg', format='svg')
```